# Asociar script a una única hoja de respuetas de formulario

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, google-forms

Tengo una función para poder enviar un correo con los datos de cada respuesta de un formulario de un libro de Google Sheets. El problema es que en ese libro tengo dos hojas independientes de respuestas de dos formularos de Google, por tanto, siempre recibo un correo con respuetas de los dos formularios. Cuando lo que realmente quiero es que el script, sólo me funcione con las respuetas de un formulario. Soy novato en esto del código, por favor, alguien me podría decir cómo lo puedo hacer?

Answer (score 0):

En la función que envía el correo, utiliza la función `getSheetByName(name)` y que funcione solo con el nombre de la hoja con las respuestas que necesitas.